# Why are trailers called "trailers"?

Tags: film-industry, terminology, trailers

Why are trailers called "trailers"? Considering [the verb "to trail" means "to follow behind"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trail), why would something that is shown **before** the main movie be called a trailer?

Comment: They used to trail and the name stuck.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As it happens, [Priceonomics has already investigated this](http://priceonomics.com/why-are-movie-trailers-called-trailers/):

> Built in the early 1900s, the United States’ first permanent movie
> theaters featured only one screen. Things worked a bit differently
> back then: you’d pay your nickel, take a seat, and watch a continuous
> loop of a feature (mixed with cartoon interludes) for as long as your
> heart desired.
>
> In 1912, Broadway producer Nils Granlund was hired as the advertising
> manager for a chain of East Coast movie theaters owned by entrepreneur
> Marcus Loew. Here, Granlund produced the first-ever trailer -- a
> one-minute spot for the upcoming Broadway show, The Pleasure Seekers
> -- which featured mainly cut up clips from the production’s rehearsals. **The advertisement was shown to audiences after the feature
> film, rather than before it.**

That's for a Broadway show, but movies followed:

> That same year, in Chicago, an early film visionary by the name of
> William Selig decided to apply 19th century society’s interest in
> print serials (stories published in installments) to films. What
> resulted was a 13-episode film serial called “The Adventures of
> Kathlyn.” As with print serials, it was important for Selig to end
> each segment on a suspenseful note, so as to encourage people to come
> see the next one. To do this, **he decided to include a brief teaser of
> "next week's" installment at the end of each one**.

But when did they start appearing before the main movie?

> Most film historians [contend](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2270/why-are-they-called-trailers-if-theyre-shown-em-before-em-the-movie) that at some point in the late
> 1930s, theaters began showing movie trailers before the feature film
> rather than afterward -- most likely because serial-style films were
> on their way out, and patrons often left the theater immediately
> following the film. Showing the trailers before, while the audience
> was obviously captive, proved more effective.

And yes, people have tried renaming them:

> “[Studios] have tried calling them ‘previews,’ or ‘prevues of coming
> attractions,’” reasoned a Paramount producer in an [interview](https://media.proquest.com/media/pq/hnp/doc/486062522/fmt/ai/rep/NONE?ic=1&_s=mLf9wUdioI3MsAsEk9PvBegoEow%3D)--
> but society has, so far, refused to accept anything other than what
> it’s used to.

Go read the whole article, it is fascinating.

Comment: FWIW, common usage in most of the places I've lived in the US would be to call them "previews" when they're shown before a film (in the theater or on DVD), but "trailer" when you're talking about, for example, finding one on the internet. I grew up in California, so if it's regional it's likely to be prominent there.

Comment: Mostly agree: I hear "trailer" exclusively when you're talking about seeking it out on the internet, but "trailer" and "preview" used pretty interchangeably when talking about seeing them attached to movies at the theater. (I also grew up in norcal then later moved to socal, but always California.)

Comment: This is an example of a good "Self Answer"!

Comment: In Australia they are called _previews_, or more formally, _coming attractions_. The article is American and has the narrow world view that is so common in American articles. (i.e. "society" is assumed to mean North American society)

Comment: To be fair. A large part of the world, especially English speaking South East Asia (hello southern neighbor!) tend to call them trailers as well - mostly because we tend to be influenced more by American culture than anything else.

Comment: What's the difference between `trailer` and `sneak preview` then? They both serve the same purpose.

Comment: @Kartagis A trailer is a short compilation of fragments, usually only a couple of minutes long, whereas a sneak preview is a showing of the full movie before it goes on general release.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Interestingly, "coming attractions" in the US tends to refer to films that will soon be shown in a theater. Most theaters have a wall in the lobby for posters for coming attractions.

Answer (score 0):

They are meant to be following the end of the previous movie until the next movie begins.